# Get top most UserRole id in a trigger without hitting governor limits

Tags: apex, trigger, governorlimits

Object: UserRole.
I am writing a trigger

Scenario: given a child record I want to traverse and get the role name of each parentId in the hierarchy. Would like to accomplish this using an apex method.

Example: r1->r2->r3->r4->..->rn etc.

Here say r1 is the input userroleId. I want to traverse to to top and while doing so want to print all the role names. I tried a code and it is hitting governor limits.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. For more about our format, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Please [edit] your question to show us the code you have written and where you are stuck, and explain the specific governor limits you have reached.

Answer (score 1):

For "normal sized" orgs, just query everything (the default limit is 500 roles).

```
static Map<Id, UserRole> roles = new Map<Id, UserRole>([SELECT ParentRoleId FROM UserRole]);
public static UserRole[] getAllParentRoles(Id userRoleId) {
    UserRole tempRole = roles.get(userRoleId);
    UserRole[] results = new UserRole[] { tempRole };
    while(tempRole != null) {
        tempRole = roles.get(tempRole.ParentRoleId);
        if(tempRole != null) {
            results.add(tempRole);
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

Unfortunately, the parent role relationship doesn't have a name, so you can't query through multiple levels, either up or down. Outside of that, you'll have to build a custom solution so you can query the data more efficiently.